# Xcode 8.1 Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: xcode, segmentation-fault, swift3

I have upgraded my app to Swift 3 and Xcode 8.1. There is a perplexing error after this update noting: `Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11` on the `FriendsViewController.swift`, but there is no other indication of error.

How can this be resolved?

**Updated: Added FriendsViewController Code**

```
import UIKit
import Contacts
import ContactsUI
import Firebase
import FBSDKCoreKit

// Allowing clean removal of objects
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Iterator.Element : Equatable {

    // Remove first collection element that is equal to the given `object`:
    mutating func removeObject(_ object : Iterator.Element) {
        if let index = self.index(of: object) {
            self.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}

// For searching
extension FriendsViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {

    // must implement to conform to the UISearchResultsUpdating protocol.
    // As well as the scope narrowing
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
        filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
    }
}

extension FriendsViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    // This delegate methods gets called when the user switches the scope in the scope bar.
    // When that happens, you want to redo the filtering,
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
    }
}

class FriendsViewController: UITableViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate  {

    // MARK: Properties
    var firebaseMainURL: String!
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    var contacts = [CNContact]()
    var friends: [Friend] = []
    var mappedFriends: [Friend] = []
    var filterMappedFriends: [Friend] = []
    var feastGlobalRef = FeastGlobal.sharedInstance
    let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    // Ensuring Serial queue
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL", attributes: [])

    // Adding search
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

        }

        // Creating the search bar, decides when to show and hide results
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        // Adding the scope bar and buttons:
        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "Friend", "A User", "Not User"]
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        // Main mapping action
        self.mapContactsToPresentFriends(feastGlobalRef.userID)

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = self.splitViewController!.collapsed
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    func findContacts() -> [CNContact] {
        let store = CNContactStore()

        let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
                           CNContactImageDataKey,
                           CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as [Any]

        let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])

        var contacts = [CNContact]()

        do {
            try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: { (contact, stop) -> Void in
                contacts.append(contact)
            })
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        return contacts
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            return filterMappedFriends.count
        }

        return self.mappedFriends.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let friend: Friend

        //let contact = contacts[indexPath.row] as CNContact
        let contact = mappedFriends[indexPath.row] as Friend

        // Getting phone number (default to first phone number present):
        let phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumber

        // If searching, then replace
        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            friend = filterMappedFriends[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            friend = mappedFriends[indexPath.row]
        }

        // Conditional given relationship:
        var status: String!

        status = {
            switch friend.statusSort {
            case 0:
                return "Invite to Feast"
            case 1:
                return "Friend them"
            default:
                return "" // they are a friend
            }
        }()

        // Update the rows with the proper object
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(friend.name) \(friend.userName)"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(status)"
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        // Ensure controller knows which dataset to pull from,
        // so detail view is correct
        var friendChat: Friend!
        if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            friendChat = filterMappedFriends[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            friendChat = mappedFriends[indexPath.row]
        }

        // Now set the conditional cases: if a friend then chat, if user then friend request if not user then can invite them:
        if(friendChat.statusSort == 2) {

            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showIndividualChat", sender: self)

        } else if (friendChat.statusSort == 1) {

            let formatterShortDate = Date().dateStringWithFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

            let myFriendPath = rootRef.child("friends").child(FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userID)

            let friendFriendsPath = rootRef.child("friends").child(friendChat.userID)

            let friendInviteSync = rootRef.child("friendInviteNeedSync").child(friendChat.userID)

            //
            let friendsObject = [
                "confirmed" : true,
                "phoneNumber" : friendChat.phoneNumber,
                "selfSendRequest" : true,
                "timeInvited": formatterShortDate,
                "userName": friendChat.userName
            ]


            let myObject = [
                "confirmed" : true,
                "phoneNumber" : FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.phoneNumber,
                "selfSendRequest" : false,
                "timeInvited": formatterShortDate,
                "userName": FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userName
            ]

            let friendInviteObject = [
                FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userID : FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userName
            ]

            queue.async {
                myFriendPath.child(friendChat.userID).setValue(friendsObject)
                friendFriendsPath.child(FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userID).setValue(myObject)
                friendInviteSync.setValue(friendInviteObject)

            }

            queue.async {
                friendFriendsPath.child(FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userID).setValue(myObject)
            }

            queue.async {
                self.mapContactsToPresentFriends(self.feastGlobalRef.userID)
            }


            print("Can invite to be friend")

        } else if (friendChat.statusSort == 0) {

            print("Invite to Feast")

        }
    }


    func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {
        let contact = contactProperty.contact
        let phoneNumber = contactProperty.value as! CNPhoneNumber

        print(contact.givenName)
        print(phoneNumber.stringValue)
    }

    // Method to match contacts with Firebase db friends:
    func mapContactsToPresentFriends(_ usersSyncID: String) {

        // Reset the data:
        self.mappedFriends.removeAll()
        self.friends.removeAll()

        // Use the queue (defined above) and "dispatch_async" to schedule the async actions, synchornously
        // First
        queue.async {
            print("start 1")

                self.contacts = self.findContacts()

            print("end 1")

        }

        // Second
        queue.async {

            let friendsURL = self.rootRef.child("friends").child(usersSyncID) // Firebase(url: firebaseMainURL + "friends/" + usersSyncID)

            var contactNumber: String?

            friendsURL.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                print("start 2")
                for oneSnapshot in snapshot.children {

                    for oneContact in self.contacts {

                        for oneContactPhoneNum in oneContact.phoneNumbers {

                            let phoneNumber = oneContactPhoneNum.value 

                            contactNumber = phoneNumber.stringValue

                            // Clean the number
                            let stringArray = contactNumber!.components(
                                separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
                            let newString = "1" + stringArray.joined(separator: "")

                            let firebaseFriendNumber = (oneSnapshot as AnyObject).value["phoneNumber"] as! String
                            print("Contacts number: " + newString)

                            print("Firebase number: " + firebaseFriendNumber)

                            if newString == firebaseFriendNumber {
                                print("friend added")

                                self.friends.append(Friend(userName: oneSnapshot.value["userName"] as! String,phoneNumber: firebaseFriendNumber, status: "Friend", statusSort: 2,  name: oneContact.givenName, userID: oneSnapshot.key))

                                // Remove that contact
                                self.contacts.removeObject(oneContact)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                print("end 2")

                print("start 3")
                // Now do the users search:
                for oneContact in self.contacts {

                    var contactNumber: String

                    let phoneNumber = oneContact.phoneNumbers[0].value 

                    contactNumber = phoneNumber.stringValue

                    let stringArray = contactNumber.components(
                        separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
                    let newString = "1" + stringArray.joined(separator: "")

                    //let usersURL: Firebase! = Firebase(url: firebaseMainURL + "presentUserIDUserNameByPhoneNumber/" + newString)
                    let usersURL = self.rootRef.child("presentUserIDUserNameByPhoneNumber").child(newString)

                    // Check db:
                    usersURL.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                        print("start 3")

                        if snapshot.childrenCount > 1 {

                            // They are users (but not your friends), and remove yourself:
                            if(snapshot.value!["userID"] as! String != FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userID) {

                                self.friends.append(Friend(userName: snapshot.value!["userName"] as! String, phoneNumber: snapshot.key, status: "A User", statusSort: 1, name: oneContact.givenName, userID: snapshot.value!["userID"] as! String))

                                let userName = snapshot.value!["userName"] as! String

                                print("Friends name: " + userName)

                            }

                        } else {

                            self.friends.append(Friend(userName: "", phoneNumber: phoneNumber.stringValue, status: "Not User", statusSort: 0, name: oneContact.givenName, userID: ""))

                        }

                        // Remove that contact
                        self.contacts.removeObject(oneContact)

                        // If all done, then sort and load main screen
                        if self.contacts.isEmpty {

                            self.mappedFriends = self.friends.sorted(by: {$0.statusSort > $1.statusSort})

                            self.tableView.reloadData()

                        }

                        print("end 3")

                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }

    func indexOfObject(_ object : AnyObject) -> NSInteger {
        return self.indexOfObject(object)
    }

    func friendRequestAction() {

        // TODO: Should siply be button to add friend, or request to feast.


    }

    // Results of search
    func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        filterMappedFriends = mappedFriends.filter { Friend in
            let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (Friend.status == scope)
            return categoryMatch && Friend.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - Segues
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            // Ensure controller knows which dataset to pull from,
            // so detail view is correct
            let friendChat: Friend
            if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
                friendChat = filterMappedFriends[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                friendChat = mappedFriends[indexPath.row]
            }

            // Now set the conditional cases: if a friend then chat, if user then friend request if not user then can invite them:

            if segue.identifier == "showIndividualChat" {

                let controller = segue.destination as! IndividualChatController
                controller.friendChat = friendChat
                controller.senderId = FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userID
                controller.senderDisplayName = FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userName
            }
        }
    }


    func getFriends() {

        let parametersfriend = ["fields": "name,picture.type(normal),gender"]

        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/friends", parameters: parametersfriend).start(completionHandler: { (connection, user, requestError) -> Void in
            if requestError != nil {
                print(requestError)
                return
            }

            print(user)

        })

    }
}
```

Specific Objects:

```
let friendsObject = [
    "confirmed" : true,
    "phoneNumber" : friendChat.phoneNumber,
    "selfSendRequest" : true,
    "timeInvited": formatterShortDate,
    "userName": friendChat.userName
]


let myObject = [
    "confirmed" : true,
    "phoneNumber" : FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.phoneNumber,
    "selfSendRequest" : false,
    "timeInvited": formatterShortDate,
    "userName": FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userName
]
```

Comment: Can you attach screenshots or something useful to solve this error?

Comment: @sohnryang I have added the error

Comment: the types aren't correct, on the friendsObject and myObject dictionary objects. Depending on your last version of working Swift, they changed it and your code is probably assuming the value of that object is something else. You now need to explicitly cast the dictionary value to what your is expecting to get from it.  If you post the code from the FriendsViewController, it will help telling you how to cast the objects properly

Comment: @JustinM I updated the question by adding the view

Comment: woah, how many lines of code you have in that VC?  where do you call the friendsObject and myObject in there? I looked through it once and couldn't find where you implement them

Comment: I updated the question with the objects pulled out, a quick `crtl+f` find for `friendsObject` will show their line appearance as well

Comment: I would give you a hardcode example but It's a pretty simple answer, wherever you retrieve the values of myObject and friendsObject, you need to cast them to whatever values the are supposed to be. For example:            guard let isConfirmed = friendsObject["confirmed"] as? Bool, let username = friendsObject["userName"] as? String else { return }

Comment: @JustinM I only use the objects to post to Firebase, there are no other references

Comment: the errors you had posted before were pointing at those and the issue with type Any, try putting [String:Any]  explicitly stating type in the objects themselves.

Comment: @JustinM the result is: `forced cast of '[String : Any]' to same type has no effect
            ] as! [String: Any]`, still fails with the same error

Comment: @JustinM I ended up solving my problem, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333868/xcode-8-swift3-command-failed-due-to-signal-segmentation-fault-11

Answer (score 0):

With the type safety of swift, right now you objects above are of type [String:Any]. When you try to use these objects, you will need to tell the compiler what you expect the types to be.

```
   let friendsObject: [String:Any] = [
        "confirmed" : true,
        "phoneNumber" : friendChat.phoneNumber,
        "selfSendRequest" : true,
        "timeInvited": formatterShortDate,
        "userName": friendChat.userName
    ]


    func doSomethingWith(FriendsObj: [String:Any] {
      guard let confirmed = friendsObject["confirmed"] as? Bool, 
      let phone = friendsObject["phoneNumber"] as? Int, 
      let sendRequest = friendsObject["selfSendRequest"] as? Bool else { return }

   //Now you can access confirmed, phone, and sendRequest as their native types.
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am not using them aside from the `myFriendPath.child(friendChat.userID).setValue(friendsObject)`, there are no other calls to these objects

Comment: alright, sorry I couldn't be more help. You should re-post the errors so if someone else comes along they will have that to go off of.

Comment: Further research notes this may be a bug in the Xcode version. There is no reason this should fail...

Comment: I elected to comment out the entire FriendsViewController, the app now runs successfully.