# Xcode 8-Swift3: Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: xcode, swift3

Upgrading to Swift 3.0 yields the errors below in my app:

```
1.  While type-checking 'mapContactsToPresentFriends' at /Users/KimiebiAkah/Desktop/iOS_Projects/FeastApp/FeastApp/FriendsViewController.swift:252:5
2.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/KimiebiAkah/Desktop/iOS_Projects/FeastApp/FeastApp/FriendsViewController.swift:270:9 - line:369:9] RangeText="queue.async {

            let friendsURL = self.rootRef.child("friends").child(usersSyncID) // Firebase(url: firebaseMainURL + "friends/" + usersSyncID)

            var contactNumber: String?

            friendsURL.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                print("start 2")
                for oneSnapshot in snapshot.children {

                    for oneContact in self.contacts {

                        for oneContactPhoneNum in oneContact.phoneNumbers {

                            let phoneNumber = oneContactPhoneNum.value 

                            contactNumber = phoneNumber.stringValue

                            // Clean the number
                            let stringArray = contactNumber!.components(
                                separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
                            let newString = "1" + stringArray.joined(separator: "")

                            let firebaseFriendNumber = (oneSnapshot as AnyObject).value["phoneNumber"] as! String
                            print("Contacts number: " + newString)

                            print("Firebase number: " + firebaseFriendNumber)

                            if newString == firebaseFriendNumber {
                                print("friend added")

                                self.friends.append(Friend(userName: oneSnapshot.value["userName"] as! String,phoneNumber: firebaseFriendNumber, status: "Friend", statusSort: 2,  name: oneContact.givenName, userID: oneSnapshot.key))

                                // Remove that contact
                                self.contacts.removeObject(oneContact)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                print("end 2")

                print("start 3")
                // Now do the users search:
                for oneContact in self.contacts {

                    var contactNumber: String

                    let phoneNumber = oneContact.phoneNumbers[0].value 

                    contactNumber = phoneNumber.stringValue

                    let stringArray = contactNumber.components(
                        separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
                    let newString = "1" + stringArray.joined(separator: "")

                    //let usersURL: Firebase! = Firebase(url: firebaseMainURL + "presentUserIDUserNameByPhoneNumber/" + newString)
                    let usersURL = self.rootRef.child("presentUserIDUserNameByPhoneNumber").child(newString)

                    // Check db:
                    usersURL.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                        print("start 3")

                        if snapshot.childrenCount > 1 {

                            // They are users (but not your friends), and remove yourself:
                            if(snapshot.value!["userID"] as! String != FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userID) {

                                self.friends.append(Friend(userName: snapshot.value!["userName"] as! String, phoneNumber: snapshot.key, status: "A User", statusSort: 1, name: oneContact.givenName, userID: snapshot.value!["userID"] as! String))

                                let userName = snapshot.value!["userName"] as! String

                                print("Friends name: " + userName)

                            }

                        } else {

                            self.friends.append(Friend(userName: "", phoneNumber: phoneNumber.stringValue, status: "Not User", statusSort: 0, name: oneContact.givenName, userID: ""))

                        }

                        // Remove that contact
                        self.contacts.removeObject(oneContact)

                        // If all done, then sort and load main screen
                        if self.contacts.isEmpty {

                            self.mappedFriends = self.friends.sorted(by: {$0.statusSort > $1.statusSort})

                            self.tableView.reloadData()

                        }

                        print("end 3")

                    })
                }
            })
        }"
3.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/KimiebiAkah/Desktop/iOS_Projects/FeastApp/FeastApp/FriendsViewController.swift:276:13 - line:368:14] RangeText="friendsURL.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                print("start 2")
                for oneSnapshot in snapshot.children {

                    for oneContact in self.contacts {

                        for oneContactPhoneNum in oneContact.phoneNumbers {

                            let phoneNumber = oneContactPhoneNum.value 

                            contactNumber = phoneNumber.stringValue

                            // Clean the number
                            let stringArray = contactNumber!.components(
                                separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
                            let newString = "1" + stringArray.joined(separator: "")

                            let firebaseFriendNumber = (oneSnapshot as AnyObject).value["phoneNumber"] as! String
                            print("Contacts number: " + newString)

                            print("Firebase number: " + firebaseFriendNumber)

                            if newString == firebaseFriendNumber {
                                print("friend added")

                                self.friends.append(Friend(userName: oneSnapshot.value["userName"] as! String,phoneNumber: firebaseFriendNumber, status: "Friend", statusSort: 2,  name: oneContact.givenName, userID: oneSnapshot.key))

                                // Remove that contact
                                self.contacts.removeObject(oneContact)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                print("end 2")

                print("start 3")
                // Now do the users search:
                for oneContact in self.contacts {

                    var contactNumber: String

                    let phoneNumber = oneContact.phoneNumbers[0].value 

                    contactNumber = phoneNumber.stringValue

                    let stringArray = contactNumber.components(
                        separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
                    let newString = "1" + stringArray.joined(separator: "")

                    //let usersURL: Firebase! = Firebase(url: firebaseMainURL + "presentUserIDUserNameByPhoneNumber/" + newString)
                    let usersURL = self.rootRef.child("presentUserIDUserNameByPhoneNumber").child(newString)

                    // Check db:
                    usersURL.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                        print("start 3")

                        if snapshot.childrenCount > 1 {

                            // They are users (but not your friends), and remove yourself:
                            if(snapshot.value!["userID"] as! String != FeastGlobal.sharedInstance.userID) {

                                self.friends.append(Friend(userName: snapshot.value!["userName"] as! String, phoneNumber: snapshot.key, status: "A User", statusSort: 1, name: oneContact.givenName, userID: snapshot.value!["userID"] as! String))

                                let userName = snapshot.value!["userName"] as! String

                                print("Friends name: " + userName)

                            }

                        } else {

                            self.friends.append(Friend(userName: "", phoneNumber: phoneNumber.stringValue, status: "Not User", statusSort: 0, name: oneContact.givenName, userID: ""))

                        }

                        // Remove that contact
                        self.contacts.removeObject(oneContact)

                        // If all done, then sort and load main screen
                        if self.contacts.isEmpty {

                            self.mappedFriends = self.friends.sorted(by: {$0.statusSort > $1.statusSort})

                            self.tableView.reloadData()

                        }

                        print("end 3")

                    })
                }
            })"
4.  While type-checking declaration 0x7fe2810d8788 at /Users/KimiebiAkah/Desktop/iOS_Projects/FeastApp/FeastApp/FriendsViewController.swift:294:29
5.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/KimiebiAkah/Desktop/iOS_Projects/FeastApp/FeastApp/FriendsViewController.swift:294:69 - line:294:108] RangeText="as AnyObject).value["phoneNumber"] as! S"
6.  While type-checking expression at [/Users/KimiebiAkah/Desktop/iOS_Projects/FeastApp/FeastApp/FriendsViewController.swift:294:69 - line:294:102] RangeText="as AnyObject).value["phoneNumber"]"
```

Is there a shortcut to resolve these areas?

Comment: I located the solution to my problem. Went through the controller and explicitly cast all array objects. ie. had: `snapshot.value["userName"] as! String`, now to: `(snapshot as AnyObject)["userName"] as! String`